# 'It took them everything they had' versus 'It took everything they had'

Tags: idioms, syntax

This question is related to the idiom
[It took everything/all I had (within me)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236556/it-took-everything-within-me)

Is it grammatically sound to place a second  object after the verb *TAKE*? To clarify what I mean, below is the sentence I want to construct:

> He was very aggressive. It took [two policemen] [everything they had] to subdue him

Or is it incorrect to do so?

> He was very aggressive. It took [everything the two policemen had] to subdue him.

Please explain.

On top of that, I would like you to provide a link to a dictionary or an article for reference, preferrably to The Free Dictionary, but any would be helpful.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The first does sound more natural, but there's nothing wrong with the second grammatically.

Comment: Wait, did you mean *everything/all* cannot be an object?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang You mean *it took two policemen everything..* sounds natural?

Comment: Correct. "It took two policemen everything they had to subdue him" sounds like the more common construction of this idiom.

Comment: Yeah I should clarify that I meant object pronouns.

Comment: Care to provide a link to a dictionary page that offers detailed explanation of this idiom?

Comment: So saying 'it took me all I had to ...' would also be good English?

Comment: Yes. But usually, we say "it took me all I had" *not* to do something. And I wouldn't want to rob you the pleasure of finding the link yourself :).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, but I have already tried searching for it for quite a while. Even just one link would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I've never heard this idiom, actually. But syntactically, *took* is not a ditransitive verb, *took + noun + noun* would be incorrect to me.

Comment: @user178049. The OP himself had posted a link to more examples of it, if you'd like a reference.

Comment: @JUNCINATOR. I see what you mean. It *is* a hard one to find. Perhaps you could ask the person who had answered the question on the ELU website?

Comment: I've edited your question for you to make it a bit clearer for readers. If you don't like the edit, please feel free to roll it back :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He was very aggressive. It took **[two policemen] [everything they had]** to subdue him

This version implies inner qualities: emotions, feelings, judgment, physical strength, trainings, presence of spirit...

> He was very aggressive. It took **[everything the two policemen had]** to subdue him.

This version implies clothes, wrist watches, jewelries, shoes, wallets...